# Go to Activity2 from Activity1 using rotation animation

Tags: android

i have activity1 and activity2 and i want to go activity2 from activity1 using rotation animation if do you have any code so please send me......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify animation for Activity transition, it is not supported by Android.
You can however specify View transitions (like rotation).

In the SDK there is a sample:
`c:\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-7\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\animation\Rotate3dAnimation.java`
Which performs a 3D rotation when switching, you can adapt it for your needs.